# NServiceBus fails to process message: The requested service 'NServiceBus.Impersonation.ExtractIncomingPrincipal' has not been registered

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0, nservicebus

I am receiving an error when using NServiceBus 4.0.3 with NHibernate 3.3.1 when it's trying to process a message

```
    INFO  NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver [(null)] <(null)> - Failed to process message
Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 'NServiceBus.Impersonation.ExtractIncomingPrincipal' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.ProcessMessage(TransportMessage message) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line 353
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.TryProcess(TransportMessage message) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line 233
   at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy.ProcessMessage(TransportMessage message) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqDequeueStrategy.cs:line 262
   at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy.Action() in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqDequeueStrategy.cs:line 197
2013-08-30 09:35:02,508 [9] WARN  NServiceBus.Faults.Forwarder.FaultManager [(null)] <(null)> - Message has failed FLR and will be handed over to SLR for retry attempt: 1, MessageID=8aaed043-b744-49c2-965d-a22a009deb32.
```

I think it's fairly obvious what that I need to implement or register an "ExtractIncomingPrincipal", but I can't seem to find any documentation on how or whether there is a default one that I can use. I wouldn't have figured that I would have had to register any of the NServiceBus-related services as many of them are already being registered in my IoC implementation.

As requested, here is the EndpointConfig and supporting code I have currently:

```
[EndpointSLA("00:00:30")]
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, IWantCustomInitialization {
    public void Init() {
        Configure.With().ObjectBuilderAdapter().UseInMemoryTimeoutPersister().UseInMemoryGatewayPersister().InMemorySagaPersister().InMemorySubscriptionStorage();
   }
}

//public class PrincipalExtractor : ExtractIncomingPrincipal {
//    public IPrincipal GetPrincipal(TransportMessage message) {
//        return Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
//    }
//}

public class ObjectBuilderAdapter : IContainer {
    readonly IDependencyInjector injector;

    public ObjectBuilderAdapter(IDependencyInjectionBuilder dependencyInjectionBuilder) {
        injector = dependencyInjectionBuilder.Create(); //This method does all the common service registrations that I am trying to re-use
        //injector.RegisterType<ExtractIncomingPrincipal, PrincipalExtractor>();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        injector.Dispose();
    }

    public object Build(Type typeToBuild) {
        return injector.Resolve(typeToBuild);
    }

    public IContainer BuildChildContainer() {
        return new ObjectBuilderAdapter(new DependencyInjectorBuilder());
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> BuildAll(Type typeToBuild) {
        return injector.ResolveAll(typeToBuild);
    }

    public void Configure(Type component, DependencyLifecycle dependencyLifecycle) {
        injector.RegisterType(component);
    }

    public void Configure<T>(Func<T> component, DependencyLifecycle dependencyLifecycle) {
            injector.RegisterType(component);
    }

    public void ConfigureProperty(Type component, string property, object value) {
        if (injector is AutofacDependencyInjector) {
          ((AutofacDependencyInjector)injector).ConfigureProperty(component, property, value);
        } else {
            Debug.WriteLine("Configuring {0} for property {1} but we don't handle this scenario.", component.Name, property);
        }
    }

    public void RegisterSingleton(Type lookupType, object instance) {
        injector.RegisterInstance(lookupType, instance);
    }

    public bool HasComponent(Type componentType) {
        return injector.IsRegistered(componentType);
    }

    public void Release(object instance) { }
}

public static class Extensions {
    public static Configure ObjectBuilderAdapter(this Configure config) {
        ConfigureCommon.With(config, new ObjectBuilderAdapter(new DependencyInjectorBuilder()));
        return config;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your endpointconfig code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the IWantCustomInitialization (left over from something else I had tried earlier) interface implementation on the class and my service now processes the message. There are errors still (relating to trying to connect to Raven [even though I thought I am using everything in-memory), but it's processing the message.